# IE 7 redirecting after jQuery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code in my file to load a div with HTML from an AJAX call:

```
$('#searchButton').click( function() {
    $('#inquiry').load('/search.php?pid=' + $('#searchValue').val());
});
```

This works fine in Firefox and Google Chrome, but whenever I do the search in IE I get redirected back to index.php. I grabbed the URL from Firebug and pasted that into IE and no redirection happens, I just get the output that should be returned.

I also tried changing it to a $.get() request and a full $.ajax() request but still the same redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More fun. I have the input text and button wrapped in this form:

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">
[HTML]
</form>
```

and IE seems to be ignoring the return false. I tried modding the jQuery function to be like Steve's but it was still refreshing inproperly.

I removed the form tags and that took care of it.

Comment: At least in XHTML it's lowercase `onsubmit`. Besides that it's better to do it via javascript - see Steve's answer.
Besides that, removing the form tags results in invalid HTML. That's a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

IE Handles default events differently (also beware of hitting enter in a text field).  IE is causing some default event handler to fire.  If searchButton is a  link with HREF of "" it will reload the current page.  You can try to set the href to  "javascript:void(0)"  or do something like:

```
$('#searchButton').click( function(e) {
    $('#inquiry').load('/search.php?pid=' + $('#searchValue').val());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set the action attribute of the form to a javascript function (e.g. your search handling  function) or "return false"

MSIE is firing the form action when you hit enter

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return false to prevent the submit action of the button. I don't know how jQuery handles that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent default like follow way ..

```
var searchbutton = $('#searchButton');
var inquirysearchvalue = $('#inquiry').load('/search.php?pid=' + $('#searchValue');

searchbutton.click( function(e) {
    inquirysearchvalue.val());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```